# trying to add a item into a cart node js

Tags: node.js, session, mongoose, cart

hi while trying to use a function "add" wich i made it seems like there is a problem wich i dont understand.
i console log "product" to see that it exists, and it does,
but when i try to use the "add" function, it just tells me that product is nod defined.

the error:[image]

my cart get route:

```
router.get('/cartAdd/:_id',(req,res)=>{
var productId = req.params._id;
console.log(productId)
var cart = new Cart(req.session.cart ? req.session.cart : {items:{}})
itemModel.findById(productId, function(err,product){
console.log(product)
console.log(product._id)
if(err){
    return res.redirect('/')
}
cart.add(product, prodcut._id)
req.session.cart = cart;
console.log(req.session.cart)
res.redirect('/')
})
})
```

my add function , inside a cart model:

```
module.exports = function Cart(oldCart){
this.items=oldCart.items;
this.totalQty=oldCart.totalQty
this.totalPrice=oldCart.totalPrice;

this.add = function(item, id){
console.log(item)
console.log(id)

var storedItem = this.items[id]
console.log(storedItem)

if(!storedItem){
storedItem = this.item[id]= {item: item, qty:0, price:0};
}
storedItem.qty++;
storedItem.price =storedItem.item.price*storedItem.qty;
this.totalQty++
this.totalPrice += storedItem.item.price;}

this.generateArry = function(){
var arr= [];
for(var id in this.items){
arr.push(this.items[id]);
}
return arr;
}
}
```

Comment: It says prodcut, not product

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo:

`cart.add(product, prodcut._id)` needs changed to `cart.add(product, product._id)`

Comment: what a 12 hours of coding doing to a man :-(, thank you very much XD